# Constructor using {a,b,c} as argument or what is {a,b,c} actually doing?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, stdinitializerlist

I know, that I can initialize data like this.

```
int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

or even

```
int array[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
```

I can also do it with `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> A = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Let's say I want to write my own class:

```
class my_class
{
     std::vector< int > A;
     public:
     //pseudo code
           my_class(*x) { store x in A;} //with x={ {1, 2}, {3, 4} }
     // do something
};
```

Is it possible to write such a constructor and how is it possible? What is this statement

`{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` actually doing?

I always just find, that you can initialize data in this way, but never what it is doing precisely.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: Write a ctor accepting `std::initializer_list` as  an argument.

Comment: I think, that's it, thanks, I didn't knew the word list_initialization, so I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called *[list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)* and you need a *[std::initilizer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)* constructor, that to be achieved in your `my_class`.

See **([Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EwL2xSbscN7Y5Sii))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list

class my_class
{
    std::vector<int> A;
public:
    // std::initilizer_list constructor 
    my_class(const std::initializer_list<int> v) : A(v) {}    

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const my_class& obj) /* noexcept */;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const my_class& obj) /* noexcept */
{
    for(const int it: obj.A) out << it << " ";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    my_class obj = {1,2,3,4};  // now possible
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) in the constructor to have such option.

```
struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;
};

struct Q {
    Q() = default;
    Q(Q const&) = default;
    Q(std::initializer_list<Q>) {}
};

int main() {
  X x;
  X x2 = X { x }; // copy-constructor (not aggregate initialization)
  Q q;
  Q q2 = Q { q }; // initializer-list constructor (not copy constructor)
}
```

Comment: is there a need for a copy constructor?

Comment: Yes it is required. `Q(Q const&) = delete;` will through error at compile time `initializer-list constructor (not copy constructor)`.

Answer (score 3):

> how is it possible?

If you have an initializer list.

```
#include  <initializer_­list> // use std::initializer_list template
my_class(const std::initializer_list<int>& v) : A(v) {}
```

> What is this statement "{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}" actually doing?

This is called [`list-initialization`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.1)

> If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=`
>   *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is *list-initialized*.