# How to declare an object which contains an array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, pointers

(C++) Hi, i have problem with declaring object, lets take a look of it first:

```
class arr1D
{
protected:
    int size;
    int *arr;
public:
    arr1D( int a[] ):size(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])), arr(new int[size])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    arr1D( int siz = 10 ):size(siz), arr(new int[size])
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    friend ostream & operator<<( ostream &,const arr1D &);
};
int main()
{
    //arr1D *a1 = new arr1D;
    //cout << *a1;
    //prints "arr: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 size: 10"
    return 0;
}
ostream & operator<<( ostream &_return, const arr1D &a)
{
    _return << "arr: ";
    for(int i=0;i<a.size;i++)
    {
        cout << *(a.arr+i) << " ";
    }
    _return << "size: " << a.size;
    return _return;
}
```

I want to declare an object which contains an array of integers
something like this:

```
arr1D a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // pseudo-code
```

This should print something like this:

```
arr: 1 2 3 4 5 size: 5
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443957/using-sizeof-on-arrays-passed-as-parameters

Comment: `arr1D( int a[] )` will not work, `a` is a pointer in this context and lost size, see how `std::vector` does it or even use `std::vector` instead

Comment: I've never used vector yet, right now i'm trying to solve it in that way. Any ideas?

Comment: unrelated, Where is the distructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor

Comment: Be **very** careful here; the constructors correctly initialize the two data members, but that's because of the **order of the declarations** of the data members, and **not** because of the order of the initializers in the constructors. Data members are initialized in the order of their declarations. If you swapped `int size;` and `int *arr;` the initialization would fail, because `arr` would be initialized before `size` was initialized.

Comment: "I've never used vector yet" it's never too early to start using `vector`. Just forget that `[]` arrays exist. Also you don't need `new` to create objects. `std::vector<int> a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` is all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to declare an object which contains an array of integers
>   something like this: (pseudocode) "arr1D a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};" This
>   should print something like this: "arr: 1 2 3 4 5 size: 5" Thanks for
>   help!

You can use it by having [initializer list constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) in your class.

Something like as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class arr1D
{
protected:
    int size;
    int *arr;
public:
    arr1D(std::initializer_list<int> input) : size(input.size())
    {
        int* temp = new int[size];
        int index = 0;
        for (const auto& it : input)
        {
            temp[index] = it;
            ++index;
        }
        arr = temp;
    }
        // reaming code...
```

See Live **[HERE](https://www.ideone.com/3uTJvJ)**

Note that, you also need a distrctor in `arr1D` class otherwise there will be a memory leak as you have pointer member in your class.

---

As an alternative, use the [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), which is the smart way of handling the dynamic memory, what you allocate in heap.

See a sample solution **[HERE](https://www.ideone.com/FdEbB1)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

class arr1D
{
protected:
    int size;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr;
public:
    arr1D(std::initializer_list<int> input) : size(input.size())
    {
        arr = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[size]);
        int index = 0;
        for (const auto& it : input)
        {
            arr[index] = it;
            ++index;
        }
    }
    .......
    .......
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &_return, const arr1D &a)
{
    _return << "arr: ";
    for (int i = 0; i< a.size; i++)  std::cout << a.arr[i] << " ";

    _return << "size: " << a.size;
    return _return;
}
```

---

**PS**:However, this is more suitable to handle with `std::vector<>`. If you do not know how that works, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489257/constructor-using-a-b-c-as-argument-or-what-is-a-b-c-actually-doing/50489350#50489350).

*Edit*: As @M.M mentioned about passing `std::initializer_list` by value is suitable rather than by reference, edited the constructor of the class.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is supposed to be passed by value  . [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803475/why-is-stdinitializer-list-often-passed-by-value)

Comment: @M.M Thanks for this answer. thats something interesting to me. `const&` is my habit actually, but its not suitable everywhere. I will edit it.